# configure IPython using start_ipython()

Tags: python, configuration, ipython

When i use a plain python shell (i hope this terminology is understandable) and then type

```
import IPython
IPython.start_ipython(["--pylab=qt", "--TerminalInteractiveShell.editor=scite"])
```

the ipython console starts just like

```
ipython --pylab=qt --TerminalInteractiveShell.editor=scite
```

but when i do the same in an already running ipython console, this does not work. Is it possible to 'reset' a running ipython console?

EDIT: I solved my problem now in my own code. Surely presenting my code here will not help anyone. On the given answers (thank you!): Typing

```
%pylab qt, %
%config TerminalInteractiveShell.editor='scite'
```

does not throw an error message. However it is NOT the same as

```
ipython --pylab=qt --TerminalInteractiveShell.editor='scite'
```

Behaviour is different and my GUI is responsive only in the latter case. I do not know why.

Comment: You can change config settings with the `%config` magic, i.e. `%config TerminalInteractiveShell.editor='scite'`.

Comment: I saw those options, but i could not find out how to mimic '--pylab=qt'. I also read somewhere, that this particular option must be set before every other option.

Comment: There's a separate `%pylab` magic to enable pylab mode. Use `%pylab qt` to make it pick the Qt backend.

Answer (score 1):

There is an IPython magic command `%reset` which will clear all variables.

You can see more details and the docstring using `%reset?`:

> Resets the namespace by removing all names defined by the user, if
>   called without arguments, or by removing some types of objects, such
>   as everything currently in IPython's In[] and Out[] containers (see
>   the parameters for details).

Comment: This command unfortunately does not reset sys.modules. And that is the problem here i fear.